# How to pass an array of numbers to a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I would like to write a stored procedure that can receive one or more employee IDs and return data based on these IDs.  The number of employee IDs will vary every time the sproc is called.

How can I write a the stored procedure to return the Branch Address of every employee ID passed in, where the number of employee IDs will be variable?

### Employee Table

- ID
- Name
- Branch_ID

### Branch Table

- ID
- Name
- Address

Comment: You could pass a `Table Valued Parameter` to the SP containing all your ID. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an SQL 2008 or higher running then I'd suggest using table types. Then you can pass a table to the stored procedure. Here is a little example I made to demonstrate just that.

```
create database tmpDB;
go

use tmpDB;
go

create table tblEmployee
    (
     ID int identity(1, 1)
            primary key
            not null,
     Name nvarchar(200),
     Branch_ID int
    );
go    

insert  into dbo.tblEmployee
        (Name, Branch_ID)
values  (N'Brian', 1),
        (N'Mary', 1),
        (N'Peter', 2),
        (N'Sonya', 2),
        (N'Roland', 1),
        (N'Tom', 3),
        (N'Sam', 3),
        (N'Ryan', 3),
        (N'Julia', 3),
        (N'Tim', 1),
        (N'Eva', 2); 
go        


select  *
from    dbo.tblEmployee;
go

create type typEmployee as table
(
Name nvarchar(200),
BranchID int
);
go

grant exec on type::typEmployee to public;
go

create procedure spInsertEmployees
    (
     @NewEmployees typEmployee readonly
    )
as
    begin
        merge tblEmployee as target
        using
            (
             select Name,
                    BranchID
             from   @NewEmployees
            ) as source (Name, BranchID)
        on (
            target.Name = source.Name
            and target.Branch_ID = source.BranchID
           )
        when not matched then
            insert (Name, Branch_ID)
            values (
                    source.Name,
                    source.BranchID
                   );
    end;
go

grant execute on spInsertEmployees to public;
go

declare @tmpTable typEmployee;
insert  into @tmpTable
        (Name, BranchID)
values  (N'NewEmployee', 1),
        (N'NewEmployee', 2),
        (N'NewEmployee', 3),
        (N'Sonya', 2),
        (N'Tim', 1);

exec dbo.spInsertEmployees
    @NewEmployees = @tmpTable;


select  *
from    dbo.tblEmployee;
go

use master;
go

drop database tmpDB;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

What we do is just pass in a delimited list.  So 1,2,3,42,55,6666 with nvarchar(max).

Then we have a user defined function that returns a table and we join on that.

Google search on t sql split string using delimiter  and you'll find examples.

select * from dbo.udfSplit(@inputfromparameters, ",")  inner join ....