# query to work for individual parameters as well as "All" case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am creating a sql server stored procedure which takes input as comma delimited productid's or  an option "All". When the user passes in comma separated productid's the query should output data for all the product Ids. I did this using an "IN" statement. When the user inputs an option "ALL" the query should display the sales data for all the Products. 
Is there any other simple way I can make my query below work for "ALL" as well as for comma separated "ProductId's" ? My query is below :

```
-- Inputs
Declare @Product varchar(max) = '0022,0033';

-- Code to split string and insert individual productIds into a temp table.
DECLARE @XML AS XML
DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR(1) =','
CREATE TABLE #ProductParams  (ProductId INT)
SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@Product,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
INSERT INTO #@ProductParams
SELECT N.value('.', 'INT') AS ID FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)

-- Sales query for all the products selected.  How can I change the below query so that it displays sales for all products when parameter "All" is passed ?  
select * from SalesTable where ProductId in (select ProductId from #ProductParams)
```

I do not want to do the following :

```
If(option is ALL)
run this query
If(option is comma seperated product ids)
run another query.
```

Comment: You can certainly stick with the parameters being passed in one string and comma separated. Yet, I'd like to suggest to pass a table to the stored procedure instead with all the parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464523/how-to-pass-an-array-of-numbers-to-a-stored-procedure/28475248#28475248 I believe that the resulting query would be also much easier with a join of the two tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering when user chose `ALL` option the `@Product` will be `NULL`

```
DECLARE @Product VARCHAR(max) = '0022,0033'; -- When user chose ALL then this will be NULL

SELECT * 
FROM   salestable 
WHERE  productid IN (SELECT productid 
                     FROM   #productparams) 
        OR @Product IS NULL
```

As mentioned in comments you can have look at `table types` which should avoid parsing `CSV` to individual rows inside procedure

```
create type product_list as table
(
productid INT -- Chose relevant datatype 
);
```

**Alter procedure**

```
Alter procedure proc_name(@prod_list product_list)
as
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM   salestable 
WHERE  productid IN (SELECT productid 
                     FROM   @prod_list) 
        OR (select count(1) from @Product) = 0
END
```

**To call**

```
declare @prod_list product_list

Insert into @prod_list(productid) values (0022),(0033)

Exec proc_name @prod_list
```